# Scala: Remove duplicates in list of objects

Tags: list, scala, collections, duplicates, sequence

I've got a list of objects `List[Object]` which are all instantiated from the same class. This class has a field which must be unique `Object.property`. What is the cleanest way to iterate the list of objects and remove all objects(but the first) with the same property?

Comment: What about using a Set instead of a List? Also, why are you dealing with Object, i.e. nearly the top of the class hierarchy?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

```
list.groupBy(_.property).map(_._2.head)
```

Explanation: The groupBy method accepts a function that converts an element to a key for grouping. `_.property` is just shorthand for `elem: Object => elem.property` (the compiler generates a unique name, something like `x$1`). So now we have a map `Map[Property, List[Object]]`. A `Map[K,V]` extends `Traversable[(K,V)]`. So it can be traversed like a list, but elements are a tuple. This is similar to Java's `Map#entrySet()`. The map method creates a new collection by iterating each element and applying a function to it. In this case the function is `_._2.head` which is shorthand for `elem: (Property, List[Object]) => elem._2.head`. `_2` is just a method of Tuple that returns the second element. The second element is List[Object] and `head` returns the first element

To get the result to be a type you want:

```
import collection.breakOut
val l2: List[Object] = list.groupBy(_.property).map(_._2.head)(breakOut)
```

To explain briefly, `map` actually expects two arguments, a function and an object that is used to construct the result. In the first code snippet you don't see the second value because it is marked as implicit and so provided by the compiler from a list of predefined values in scope. The result is usually obtained from the mapped container. This is usually a good thing. map on List will return List, map on Array will return Array etc. In this case however, we want to express the container we want as result. This is where the breakOut method is used. It constructs a builder (the thing that builds results) by only looking at the desired result type. It is a generic method and the compiler infers its generic types because we explicitly typed l2 to be `List[Object]` or, to preserve order (assuming `Object#property` is of type `Property`):

```
list.foldRight((List[Object](), Set[Property]())) {
  case (o, cum@(objects, props)) => 
    if (props(o.property)) cum else (o :: objects, props + o.property))
}._1
```

`foldRight` is a method that accepts an initial result and a function that accepts an element and returns an updated result. The method iterates each element, updating the result according to applying the function to each element and returning the final result. We go from right to left (rather than left to right with `foldLeft`) because we are prepending to `objects` - this is O(1), but appending is O(N). Also observe the good styling here, we are using a pattern match to extract the elements.

In this case, the initial result is a pair (tuple) of an empty list and a set. The list is the result we're interested in and the set is used to keep track of what properties we already encountered. In each iteration we check if the set `props` already contains the property (in Scala, `obj(x)` is translated to `obj.apply(x)`. In `Set`, the method `apply` is `def apply(a: A): Boolean`. That is, accepts an element and returns true / false if it exists or not). If the property exists (already encountered), the result is returned as-is. Otherwise the result is updated to contain the object (`o :: objects`) and the property is recorded (`props + o.property`)

Update: @andreypopp wanted a generic method:

```
import scala.collection.IterableLike
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom

class RichCollection[A, Repr](xs: IterableLike[A, Repr]){
  def distinctBy[B, That](f: A => B)(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, A, That]) = {
    val builder = cbf(xs.repr)
    val i = xs.iterator
    var set = Set[B]()
    while (i.hasNext) {
      val o = i.next
      val b = f(o)
      if (!set(b)) {
        set += b
        builder += o
      }
    }
    builder.result
  }
}

implicit def toRich[A, Repr](xs: IterableLike[A, Repr]) = new RichCollection(xs)
```

to use:

```
scala> list.distinctBy(_.property)
res7: List[Obj] = List(Obj(1), Obj(2), Obj(3))
```

Also note that this is pretty efficient as we are using a builder. If you have really large lists, you may want to use a mutable HashSet instead of a regular set and benchmark the performance.

Comment: Would be awesome if you can provide a quick explanation. I think Scala is sufficiently new that not everyone will understand this immediately.

Comment: Specifically, what does `_2` do in this context?

Comment: @Sudhir: _1 and _2 are methods that return the first and second element of a tuple.

Comment: ref 2nd solution, Property is not a type so you can't do Set[Property] to my understanding.

Comment: Maybe scala collection needs distinct(A => B), that do distinct by key?

Comment: +1, This method - `distinctBy` - should be added to the stdlib, methinks.

Comment: @IttayD Awesome sauce. Just a quick question. Could you explain what That does? I am pretty junior at Scala and just started using it in production in earnest a few months back. Cheers.

Comment: @Andrew, `That` is the type of the result collection. The  compiler will search for a CanBuildFrom that has the types of the source collection, the result of f and That. If it can infer That from the context of the call (for example, you assign the result to a known type variable), it'll use it, otherwise it'll fall back to the most generic type it can find. By using CanBuildFrom, we allow to directly return the expected type, rather than something generic that them needs to be converted.

Comment: @IttayD thank you very much for the generic approach. If we use `hashSet`, is the whole object stored in the hashSet?  I guess ```val b = f(o)``` is apply a function to the generic object?

Comment: @soMuchToLearnAndShare, in Scala and Java, objects are not values, rather the reference to the object is. So the hashSet will contain the references. `f(o)` indeed applies f on o

Answer (score 39):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, most collections are now provided with a [`distinctBy`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#distinctBy[B](f:A=%3EB):C) method which returns all elements of the sequence ignoring the duplicates after applying a given transforming function:

```
list.distinctBy(_.property)
```

For instance:

```
List(("a", 2), ("b", 2), ("a", 5)).distinctBy(_._1) // List((a,2), (b,2))
List(("a", 2.7), ("b", 2.1), ("a", 5.4)).distinctBy(_._2.floor) // List((a,2.7), (a,5.4))
```

Comment: The answer to every one

Answer (score 14):

Here is a little bit sneaky but fast solution that preserves order:

```
list.filterNot{ var set = Set[Property]()
    obj => val b = set(obj.property); set += obj.property; b}
```

Although it uses internally a var, I think it is easier to understand and to read than the foldLeft-solution.

Comment: I'm clearly missing something here. What is Property exactly?

Comment: @parsa28: Property is the type of obj.property

Answer (score 10):

A lot of good answers above. However, `distinctBy` is already in Scala, but in a not-so-obvious place. Perhaps you can use it like

```
def distinctBy[A, B](xs: List[A])(f: A => B): List[A] =
  scala.reflect.internal.util.Collections.distinctBy(xs)(f)
```

Comment: I came here just to upvote and say that those functions being in the reflect package makes 0 to no sense.

Answer (score 7):

With preserve order:

```
def distinctBy[L, E](list: List[L])(f: L => E): List[L] =
  list.foldLeft((Vector.empty[L], Set.empty[E])) {
    case ((acc, set), item) =>
      val key = f(item)
      if (set.contains(key)) (acc, set)
      else (acc :+ item, set + key)
  }._1.toList

distinctBy(list)(_.property)
```

Comment: You can use Seq[L] for a more generic solution.

Answer (score 6):

One more solution

```
@tailrec
def collectUnique(l: List[Object], s: Set[Property], u: List[Object]): List[Object] = l match {
  case Nil => u.reverse
  case (h :: t) => 
    if (s(h.property)) collectUnique(t, s, u) else collectUnique(t, s + h.prop, h :: u)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to make it work with groupBy, with one intermediary step:

```
def distinctBy[T, P, From[X] <: TraversableLike[X, From[X]]](collection: From[T])(property: T => P): From[T] = {
  val uniqueValues: Set[T] = collection.groupBy(property).map(_._2.head)(breakOut)
  collection.filter(uniqueValues)
}
```

Use it like this:

```
scala> distinctBy(List(redVolvo, bluePrius, redLeon))(_.color)
res0: List[Car] = List(redVolvo, bluePrius)
```

Similar to IttayD's first solution, but it filters the original collection based on the set of unique values. If my expectations are correct, this does three traversals: one for `groupBy`, one for `map` and one for `filter`. It maintains the ordering of the original collection, but does not necessarily take the first value for each property. For example, it could have returned `List(bluePrius, redLeon)` instead.

Of course, IttayD's solution is still faster since it does only one traversal.

My solution also has the disadvantage that, if the collection has `Car`s that are actually the same, both will be in the output list. This could be fixed by removing `filter` and returning `uniqueValues` directly, with type `From[T]`. However, it seems like `CanBuildFrom[Map[P, From[T]], T, From[T]]` does not exist... suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

With a collection and a function from a record to a key this yields a list of records distinct by key. It's not clear whether groupBy will preserve the order in the original collection.  It may even depend on the type of collection.  I'm guessing either `head` or `last` will consistently yield the earliest element.

```
collection.groupBy(keyFunction).values.map(_.head)
```

When will Scala get a `nubBy`?  It's been in Haskell for decades.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove duplicates and ***preserve the order of the list*** you can try this two liner:

```
val tmpUniqueList = scala.collection.mutable.Set[String]()
val myUniqueObjects = for(o <- myObjects if tmpUniqueList.add(o.property)) yield o
```

Answer (score 0):

this is entirely a rip of @IttayD 's answer, but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to comment.
Rather than creating an implicit function to convert your iteratble, you can simply create an implicit class:

```
import scala.collection.IterableLike
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom

implicit class RichCollection[A, Repr](xs: IterableLike[A, Repr]){
  def distinctBy[B, That](f: A => B)(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, A, That]) = {
    val builder = cbf(xs.repr)
    val i = xs.iterator
    var set = Set[B]()
    while (i.hasNext) {
      val o = i.next
      val b = f(o)
      if (!set(b)) {
        set += b
        builder += o
      }
    }
    builder.result
  }
}
```