# Remove duplicates in List specifying equality function

Tags: scala

I have a `List[A]`, how is a idiomatic way of removing duplicates given an equality function `(a:A, b:A) => Boolean`? I cannot generally override `equals`for `A`

The way I can think now is creating a wrapping `class AExt` with overridden `equals`, then

> list.map(new AExt(_)).distinct

But I wonder if there's a cleaner way.

Comment: You might be interested in looking at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739432/how-to-implement-a-set-with-a-user-defined-equality

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala: Remove duplicates in list of objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912753/scala-remove-duplicates-in-list-of-objects)

Comment: @ptay89 although the solution is the same, I believe it is a different question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I must say I think I'd go via an intermediate collection which was a `Set` if you expected that your `List`s might be quite long as **testing for presence** (via `exists` or `find`) on a `Seq` is **O(n)** of course:

Rather than write a custom equals; decide what *property* the elements are equal by. So instead of:

```
def myCustomEqual(a1: A, a2: A) = a1.foo == a2.foo && a1.bar == a2.bar
```

Make a *Key*. Like so:

```
type Key = (Foo, Bar)
def key(a: A) = (a.foo, a.bar)
```

Then you can add the keys to a `Set` to see whether you have come across them before.

```
var keys = Set.empty[Key]
((List.empty[A] /: as) { (l, a) => 
  val k = key(a)
  if (keys(k)) l else { keys += k; a +: l  }
}).reverse
```

Of course, this solution has worse space complexity and *potentially worse performance* (as you are creating extra objects - the keys) in the case of very short lists. If you do not like the `var` in the fold, you might like to look at how you could achieve this using `State` and `Traverse` from **scalaz** 7

Comment: Ended up implemeting something simpler but based on your suggestion by identifying the keys.

Answer (score 19):

There is a simple (simpler) way to do this:

```
list.groupBy(_.key).mapValues(_.head)
```

If you want you can use the resulting map instantly by replacing `_.head` by a function block like:

```
sameElements => { val observedItem = sameElements.head
                  new A (var1 = observedItem.firstAttr,
                         var2 = "SomethingElse") }
```

to return a new `A` for each distinct element.

There is only one minor problem. The above code (`list.groupBy(_.key).mapValues(_.head)`) didnt explains very well the intention to remove duplicates. For that reason it would be great to have a function like `distinctIn[A](attr: A => B)` or `distinctBy[A](eq: (A, A) -> Boolean)`.

Comment: This way the result will be a map on the unique key.
To get just distinct values, one should .map(_._2.head)

Comment: This works in most cases; care should be taken in lazy evaluation cases, because `groupBy` tends to imply eager evaluation.

Answer (score 8):

Using the `Foo` and `customEquals` from misingFaktor's answer:

```
  case class Foo(a: Int, b: Int)
  val (a, b, c, d) = (Foo(3, 4), Foo(3, 1), Foo(2, 5), Foo(2, 5))
  def customEquals(x: Foo, y: Foo) = x.a == y.a

  (Seq(a, b, c, d).foldLeft(Seq[Foo]()) {
    (unique, curr) => {
      if (!unique.exists(customEquals(curr, _)))
        curr +: unique
      else
        unique
    }
  }).reverse
```

If result ordering is important but the duplicate to be removed is not, then foldRight is preferable

```
  Seq(a, b, c, d).foldRight(Seq[Foo]()) {
    (curr, unique) => {
      if (!unique.exists(customEquals(curr, _)))
        curr +: unique
      else
        unique
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
scala> case class Foo(a: Int, b: Int)
defined class Foo

scala> val (a, b, c, d) = (Foo(3, 4), Foo(3, 1), Foo(2, 5), Foo(2, 5))
a: Foo = Foo(3,4)
b: Foo = Foo(3,1)
c: Foo = Foo(2,5)
d: Foo = Foo(2,5)

scala> def customEquals(x: Foo, y: Foo) = x.a == y.a
customEquals: (x: Foo, y: Foo)Boolean

scala> Seq(a, b, c, d) filter {
     |   var seq = Seq.empty[Foo]
     |   x => {
     |    if(seq.exists(customEquals(x, _))) {
     |      false 
     |    } else { 
     |      seq :+= x
     |      true 
     |    }
     | }
res13: Seq[Foo] = List(Foo(3,4), Foo(2,5))
```

Comment: This answer is inspired by the implementation of `distinct`: https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_1_final/src//library/scala/collection/SeqLike.scala#L501 So looking at the source code can sometimes help.

Comment: No, this answer not inspired by that implementation. I wrote something that came to my mind. This is actually not even a good solution. @drstevens' answer is better.

Comment: My bad, I looked for how it was implemented in scala, as I consider it as a good source of inspiration and then saw that it was the same form as your implementation. However I agree with you that a `foldleft` is more elegant.

Answer (score 3):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, we can use the new [`distinctBy`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#distinctBy[B](f:A=%3EB):C) method which returns elements of a sequence ignoring the duplicates as determined by `==` after applying a transforming function `f`:

> def distinctBy[B](f: (A) => B): List[A]

For instance:

```
// case class A(a: Int, b: String, c: Double)
// val list = List(A(1, "hello", 3.14), A(2, "world", 3.14), A(1, "hello", 12.3))
list.distinctBy(x => (x.a, x.b)) // List(A(1, "hello", 3.14), A(2, "world", 3.14))
list.distinctBy(_.c)             // List(A(1, "hello", 3.14), A(1, "hello", 12.3))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
case class Foo (a: Int, b: Int)

val x = List(Foo(3,4), Foo(3,1), Foo(2,5), Foo(2,5))
def customEquals(x : Foo, y: Foo) = (x.a == y.a && x.b == y.b)

x.foldLeft(Nil : List[Foo]) {(list, item) => 
   val exists = list.find(x => customEquals(item, x))
   if (exists.isEmpty) item :: list
   else list
 }.reverse
```

res0: List[Foo] = List(Foo(3,4), Foo(3,1), Foo(2,5))