# Call distinct on an immutable list with a custom equality relation in Scala

Tags: scala

I'd like to extract the distinct elements from a Scala list, but I don't want to use the natural equality relation. How can I specify it?

Do I have to rewrite the function or is there any way (maybe using some implicit definition that I am missing) to invoke the `distinct` method with a custom equality relation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala: Remove duplicates in list of objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912753/scala-remove-duplicates-in-list-of-objects)

Comment: @Eduardo toSet relies on default equality relation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`distinct` does not expect an ordering algorithm - it uses the equals-method ([source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/collection/SeqLike.scala#L501)).

One way to achieve what you want is to create your own ordering and pass it to a `SortedSet`, which expects an `Ordering`:

```
implicit val ord = new Ordering[Int] {
  def compare(i: Int, j: Int) = /* your implementation here */
}
val sortedList = collection.immutable.SortedSet(list: _*)/*(ord)*/.toList
```

Comment: @thatha Thanks for the edit. I think it was rejected because the ordering should not be added explicitly. But the suggestion to add `: _*` is correct.