# How to make a scala collection contain unique elements? ("unique" defined)

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Say I have a list as follows:

```
val l = List( (1, 2, "hi"), (1, 3, "hello"), (2, 3, "world"), (1, 2, "hello") )
```

I want to make the elements of `l` distinct ignoring the 3rd element of the tuple. That is, two elements of `l` are considered same if their first two components are same.

So `makeDistinct(l)` should return

```
List( (1, 2, "hi"), (1, 3, "hello"), (2, 3, "world") )
```

What is the most Scala-like and generic way to do implement `makeDistinct`

EDIT: We are free to choose which to drop, and ordering need not be preserved.

Comment: Is it required that the ordering of the elements is preserved?

Comment: @sschaef no the ordering need not be preserved.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala: Remove duplicates in list of objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912753/scala-remove-duplicates-in-list-of-objects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do this with lists, use `groupBy`:

```
l.groupBy(x => (x._1, x._2)).map(kv => kv._2.head).toList
```

If you really want to be generic for all collection types:

```
scala> import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom

scala> def distinct[A, B, C, CC[X] <: Traversable[X]](xs: CC[(A, B, C)])(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Nothing, (A, B, C), CC[(A, B, C)]]): CC[(A, B, C)] = xs.groupBy(x => (x._1, x._2)).map(kv => kv._2.head).to[CC]
warning: there were 1 feature warnings; re-run with -feature for details
distinct: [A, B, C, CC[X] <: Traversable[X]](xs: CC[(A, B, C)])(implicit cbf: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Nothing,(A, B, C),CC[(A, B, C)]])CC[(A, B, C)]

scala> distinct(List((1, 2, "ok"), (1, 3, "ee"), (1, 2, "notok")))
res0: List[(Int, Int, String)] = List((1,3,ee), (1,2,ok))
```

Comment: thanks. This really helped. The generic answer in the "related question" did not clarify how we can match two elements together.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Ordering`:

```
scala> SortedSet(l: _*)(Ordering[(Int, Int)].on(x => (x._1, x._2))).toList
res33: List[(Int, Int, String)] = List((1,2,hello), (1,3,hello), (2,3,world))
```

The only problem is that the last found element is preserved. For the first one you need to reverse the list:

```
scala> SortedSet(l.reverse: _*)(Ordering[(Int, Int)].on(x => (x._1, x._2))).toList
res34: List[(Int, Int, String)] = List((1,2,hi), (1,3,hello), (2,3,world))
```

The reverse is not optimal but maybe it is possible to create the list directly in reversed order, which would avoid the construction of an unnecessary intermediate list.