# Returning distinct elements of type ((String,String) , Double)

Tags: scala

```
val v : Array[((String, String), Double)] = Array( ( ("a" , "b") , 1.0) , (("b" , "a") , 1.0) )
                                                  //> v  : Array[((String, String), Double)] = Array(((a,b),1.0), ((b,a),1.0))

  val d = v.distinct                              //> d  : Array[((String, String), Double)] = Array(((a,b),1.0), ((b,a),1.0))
```

A distinct function should output `( ("a" , "b") , 1.0)` since `(("b" , "a") , 1.0)` is in the array

Using :

```
  Array( ( ("a" , "b") , 1.0) , (("a" , "b") , 1.0) ).distinct
```

returns the distinct elements : `Array(((a,b),1.0))`

Can distinct function be modified to return the distinct Tuple elements regardless of their ordering or do I need to swap the positions of the tuples so that each element appears ordered ?

Comment: It sounds like you want to redefine the behavior of `equals` for `Tuple2`, rather than `distinct` for a collection.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala: Remove duplicates in list of objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912753/scala-remove-duplicates-in-list-of-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed tuple t1: (A, B) is not equal to t2: (B, A) because the order is important (`t1._1 != t2._1`). If you want a data structure which does not preserve order and thus does not use it when being compared to another instance then use something like `Set`. Just to illustrate the point:

```
scala> (1, 2) == (2, 1)
res0: Boolean = false

scala> Set(1, 2) == Set(2, 1)
res1: Boolean = true
```

If you still want to use tuples then you can write your own implementation of `distinct`. Unfortunately, `distinct` is not a higher order function which can use comparison strategy like `def sorted[B >: A](implicit ord: math.Ordering[B]): List[A]`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on LimbSoup's comment:

If you were willing to use another case class in place of a `Tuple2`, you can easily create your own unordered tuple implementation with `equals(Any)` overriden:

```
case class UT2[+T1, +T2](_1: T1, _2: T2)  {
  override def hashCode(): Int = _1.hashCode() ^ _2.hashCode()

  override def equals(that: Any): Boolean ={
   that match {
    case UT2(o1, o2) => (_1 == o1 && _2 == o2) || (_1 == o2 && _2 == o1)
    case _ => false
  }}

  lazy val tuple: (T1, T2) = (_1, _2)
}
```

Note that you have to override `hashCode()`, otherwise it won't work with `distinct` which seems to be using a hash set internally and [just because you should](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27609/246337).

```
val seq = Array((UT2("a", "b") , 1.0), (UT2("b", "a"), 1.0))
seq.distinct.toList // List((UT2(a,b),1.0))
```

If you want automatic conversions between a normal tuple and the unordered tuple in most places you can provide implicit conversions:

```
object UnorderedTupleImplicits {
  implicit def Tuple2UnorderedTuple[T1, T2](t: (T1, T2)): UT2[T1, T2] = UT2(t._1, t._2)
  implicit def UnorderedTuple2Tuple[T1, T2](ut: UT2[T1, T2]): (T1, T2) = ut.tuple
}
import UnorderedTupleImplicits._
val ut: (UT2[String, String], Double) = (("a", "b"), 1.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Aleksey Izmailov answer as base :

```
    val v : Array[((String, String), Double)] = Array( ( ("a" , "b") , 1.0) , (("b" , "a") , 1.0) )    
      v.map(m => (Set(m._1._1 , m._1._2) , m._2) ).distinct
 res0: Array[(scala.collection.immutable.Set[String], Double)] = Array((Set(a, b),1.0))
```

Comment: what do you want to happen if you have a tuple of two strings that are the same? Like `(("a", "a"), 1.0)`?