# Removing duplicates from Spark RDDPair values

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to Python and also Spark.
I've an pair RDD containing (key, List) but some of the values are duplicate.
RDD is of the form (zipCode,streets)
I want a pair RDD which does not contain duplicates.
I am trying to achieve it using python.
Can anyone please help on this.

(zipcode, streets)

```
streetsGroupedByZipCode = zipCodeStreetsPairTuple.groupByKey()
dayGroupedHosts.take(2)

[(123456, <pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable at 0xb00518ec>),
 (523900, <pyspark.resultiterable.ResultIterable at 0xb005192c>)]

zipToUniqueStreets = streetsGroupedByZipCode.map(lambda (x,y):(x,y.distinct()))
```

Above one does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do something like this :

```
streetsGroupedByZipCode.map(x => (x._1, x._2.groupBy(_._2).map(_._2.head)))
```

distinct on a tuple doesn't work as you said, so group your list by tuple, and get only the first element at the end.

```
val data = Seq((1, Seq((1, 1), (2, 2), (2, 2))), (10, Seq((1, 1), (1, 1), (3, 3))), (10, Seq((1, 2), (2, 4), (1, 2))))
```

gives :

```
(10,Map(1 -> 1, 3 -> 3))
(1,Map(2 -> 2, 1 -> 1))
(10,Map(1 -> 2, 2 -> 4))
```

Comment: this is more a question of tuples as treated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912753/scala-remove-duplicates-in-list-of-objects