# In Scala, is there a simple way to get a distinct list of elements based on the results of a function?

Tags: scala

I see that Scala has a [`distinct`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/SeqLike.html#distinct:Repr) method which will take a sequence and return a new sequence without any duplicate elements.

```
Seq(1,1,2,3,2,5).distinct // returns Seq(1,2,3,5)
```

I would like to do something similar, but base the uniqueness on the results of a function.  Is there a clean idiomatic way to do this in Scala?

As an example in another language, I know Groovy's analogous [`unique`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#unique(groovy.lang.Closure)) method can take a closure to determine the uniqueness function:

```
[1,3,4,5].unique { it % 2 } // returns [1,4]
```

Is there a similarly short and descriptive approach in Scala, or am I best served with something like the following?

```
Seq(1,3,4,5).groupBy(_ % 2).values.map(_.head)
```

Comment: Very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912753/scala-remove-duplicates-in-list-of-objects

Comment: @XavierGuihot Good find.  I had no luck finding the other question, probably since I was searching for it based on the inverse definition (retaining distinct elements vs. removing duplicate ones)

Comment: I think it's difficult to add anything to the duplicate proposed by XavierGuihot, please leave a comment if you disagree.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Nope, marking as a duplicate seems reasonable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52600508/1108305) to a similar question, Scala 2.13 adds a [`distinctBy`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#distinctBy[B](f:A=%3EB):C) method to sequences:

```
Seq(1,3,4,5).distinctBy(_ % 2)
```