# scala filter list of object if some fields in the object are same

Tags: scala

I have a list of object PersonInfo,  if certain fields in the PersonInfo object are same with another PersonInfo object, i'll say these two objects are duplicated. 
example:

```
case class PersonInfo(
    firstName: Instant,
    lastName: Instant,
    ssn: String,
    email: String
)
```

if two PersonInfo objects have same 'ssn', they are duplicated record. 
my list looks like this:

```
val list = List(pi1, pi2, pi3)
pi1 is: PersonInfo("foo", "foo", "123-456-789", "foo@f.com")
pi2 is: PersonInfo("bar", "bar", "456-123-789", "bar@b.com")
pi3 is: PersonInfo("gee", "gee", "123-456-789", "gee@g.org)
```

how can i filter the list to only return list of (pi1 and pi3) since pi1 and pi3 are duplicated:

```
list.filter(f => pi1.ssn == pi3.ssn) => ???
```

and I expect it to return List(pi1, pi2)

Comment: You'll probably find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912753/scala-remove-duplicates-in-list-of-objects

Comment: You can override the `equals` method on your case class and use `distinct`.

Comment: I think this part of the question `only return list of (pi1 and pi3)` conflicts with `expect it to return List(pi1, pi2)`

Answer (score 3):

Group them, keep only the duplicates, return as `List`.

```
list.groupBy(_.ssn).values.filter(_.length > 1).flatten.toList
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `groupBy` + `flatMap`:

```
val pi1 = PersonInfo("foo", "foo", "123-456-789", "foo@f.com")
val pi2 = PersonInfo("bar", "bar", "456-123-789", "bar@b.com")
val pi3 = PersonInfo("gee", "gee", "123-456-789", "gee@g.org")

val list = List(pi1, pi2, pi3)

val onlyDuplicates = list
    .groupBy(_.ssn)
    .flatMap{
      case (_, v) if v.length > 1 => v //take only elements that have 1+ occurence
      case _ => Nil
    }

println(onlyDuplicates) // List(pi1, pi3)
```