# List.distinct not removing duplicates of class with equals override

Tags: scala, duplicates

Using below code I'm attempting to remove duplicate elements using the `distinct` method on List :

```
class OrderDetSpecific(var size: Double,
                       var side: String,
                       var trade_id: Int,
                       var price: Double,
                       var time: String,
                       var code : String) {

  override def toString : String = {
    this.code+","+this.time+","+this.trade_id+","+this.price
  }

}


val l = List(new OrderDetSpecific(1.0 , "1" , 1 , 1.0 , "10" , "a"),new OrderDetSpecific(1.0 , "1" , 1 , 1.0 , "10" , "a"))

println(l.size)
println(l.distinct.size)
```

returns :

```
defined class OrderDetSpecific

l: List[OrderDetSpecific] = List(a,10,1,1.0, a,10,1,1.0)

2
2
```

But as can see the duplicated elements are not being removed. Overriding the `toString` method is utilized as a part of discovering duplicates and as the duplicates entries exist then the List `l` should be of size 1 instead of 2 as a result of calling `l.distinct.size`?

Update :

Converting to case class :

```
case class OrderDetSpecific(var size: Double,
                       var side: String,
                       var trade_id: Int,
                       var price: Double,
                       var time: String,
                       var code : String) {

  override def toString : String = {
    this.code+","+this.time+","+this.trade_id+","+this.price
  }

}


val l = List(new OrderDetSpecific(1.0 , "1" , 1 , 1.0 , "10" , "a"),new OrderDetSpecific(1.0 , "1" , 1 , 1.0 , "10" , "a"))

println(l.size)
println(l.distinct.size)
```

now the duplicated elements are removed. Does a case class use value equality on equals which allows `distinct` to behave as expected ?

When I override equals :

```
class OrderDetSpecific(var size: Double,
                       var side: String,
                       var trade_id: Int,
                       var price: Double,
                       var time: String,
                       var code : String) {

  override def toString : String = {
    this.code+","+this.time+","+this.trade_id+","+this.price
  }

  override def equals(that: Any): Boolean =
    that match {
      case that: OrderDetSpecific => {
        time == that.time
      }
      case _ => false
    }

}


val l = List(new OrderDetSpecific(1.0 , "1" , 1 , 1.0 , "10" , "a"),new OrderDetSpecific(1.0 , "1" , 1 , 1.0 , "10" , "a"))

println(l.size)
println(l.distinct.size)
```

The distinct element is not removed. As my override is on `time` attribute which is not distinct shouldnt the duplicated element be removed ?

Comment: `distinct` internally uses `equals` which for normal classes uses **reference equality** instead of **value equality**, so all those elements are different regardless they have the same values _(also given all those values are mutable, they having the same values is just a coincidence that may be changed later)_. - So it is behaving as expected. If you want, you could either make all those values immutable and use a **case class** instead, or you can override `equals` yourself _(but remember that for mutable values, **reference equality** is the only "sane" implementation)_.

Comment: it's not evil to just add `case` for a holder of vars in a list. But prefer immutable and careful with Maps and Sets.

Comment: @texasbruce probably he was talking about "human readability" to verify the output.

Comment: @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez thanks, please see question update. Why is it " for mutable values, reference equality is the only "sane" implementation " ?

Comment: @blue-sky a **case class** with mutable values is a code smell. For your own equals, probably you also need to override `canEquals` & `hashcode`, you can search about that by googling _"effective Java custom equals"_, or that is why in **Scala** we usually do not worry about that and just use `case classes`. Finally, for mutable values one may argue that they are only equals if they are exactly the same instance. **value equality** for something whose values can change doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As my override is on time attribute which is not distinct shouldnt the
>   duplicated element be removed ?

No, because `distinct` is equivalent to `distinctBy(identity)` and [`distinctBy`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/7bfe4c09a5fc72d9ef8103c3e0a3cefb469fa14b/src/library/scala/collection/Iterator.scala#L547) uses `HashSet` which uses `hashCode` to eliminate duplicates, however you have not provided an override for `hashCode`. For example, without `hashCode` override

```
class Foo(var x: Int) {
  override def equals(obj: Any): Boolean = true
}

val a = new Foo(42)
val b = new Foo(42)

a.## == b.##
mutable.HashSet(a, b).size == 1
```

outputs

```
res0: Boolean = false
res1: Boolean = false
```

whilst with `hashCode` override provided

```
class Foo(var x: Int) {
  override def equals(obj: Any): Boolean = true
  override def hashCode(): Int = scala.runtime.Statics.anyHash(x)
}
...
```

we get

```
res0: Boolean = true
res1: Boolean = true
```

However, there is no need to fiddle with these overrides, instead [try](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52600508/5205022)

```
l.distinctBy(_.time)
```

which outputs

```
res0: List[OrderDetSpecific] = List(a,10,1,1.0)
```